# Embedding CSS is causing webpage to render badly

Tags: html, css, embedding

I'm doing some experiments to see the potential pros&cons of embedding css in HTML. I have mirror of websites locally. I tried to embed external css into HTML using "style type='text/css'" tag. Its working for few css files but for some css webpage is not rendered exactly as it used to be before embedding. I'm not sure whats exactly causing this problem.

Any suggestions/help please.. Pictures before and after ebedding. [image: Before embedding]

[image: After embedding]
Problem is not particular to this site. I'm seeing different rendering problems for different websites. I want to know whats the difference of embedding vs referring external css?

Comment: can you show your error or your HTML page?

Comment: "webpage is not rendered exactly as it used to be before embedding". Isn't that the point of CSS?

Comment: Please provide a *code* example in which there is a problem. This is very hard to debug an image you know

Comment: I'm not getting whats the difference of putting css in a external file and including it in html vs embedding the same content in style tag.

Comment: CSS file is very huge.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is mainly caused by relative paths being invalid once you embed your css. Let assume that the image *Evil_Kitty_Of_Darnkess.JPG* is one level higher than the css file. A rule inside the file will be able to use the relative path like this:

```
background-image: url(../Evil_Kitty_Of_Darnkess.JPG);
```

Once you embed those rules directly in the page, you must reference paths according to the new base path in which the page is located. If the image isn't exactly one level higher, it will fail to resolve it. You will see something like in your screenshot: Nothing at all.

Comment: Got it. Thats the actual problem. I didn't think of this, I'm thinking from the perspective of styles being overridden. Thanks!!